# How to fix error "clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, clang++

When compiling my C++ program containing main.cpp, pattern.cpp, and pattern.h (a header file containing two function declarations but no class; those functions are defined in pattern.cpp and main.cpp contains #include "pattern.h" at the top) by typing:

```
clang++ main.cpp
```

Error message was:

```
/tmp/cc-nrPup0.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `pattern(int, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How do I fix this? I tried typing `-v` but the clang output had terminated and that was an invalid command

Comment: show the commands you used to build in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only compiled `main.cpp` but not `pattern.cpp`. When it came time to link the executable together, functions defined in `pattern.cpp` won't be found. The undefined reference indicates your `main.cpp` is using `pattern(int, int)` somewhere. You can see why this becomes a problem if `pattern.cpp` is never compiled in.

Try compiling with:

```
clang++ -Wall -pedantic main.cpp pattern.cpp -o main
```